# Azure Active Directory: Where can I insert a function to run after a user is signed in?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've been following this example https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/ and I'm pretty certain that in the `SignIn` method I can put my function there to run, but I'm not sure how you would go

In that top portion of the AccountController.cs example:

```
namespace WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet_B2C.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // To execute a policy, you simply need to trigger an OWIN challenge.
                // You can indicate which policy to use by adding it to the AuthenticationProperties using the PolicyKey provided.

                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties (
                        new Dictionary<string, string> 
                        { 
                            {Startup.PolicyKey, Startup.SignInPolicyId}
                        })
                    { 
                        RedirectUri = "/", 
                    }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```

Where do I insert toDoAfterSignedIn(); method ? or is this the wrong way of doing it, is there some listener or event emitter that will notify me when a user has successfully signed in?

https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

Comment: What are you going to do in toDoAfterSignedIn()?

Comment: I want to fire off a message to the end user via Bot Framework API saying they are logged in. Their phone number should be stored as a separate custom attribute in the b2c_Sign-In policy. Once they have MFA'd, fire http request to Bot Framework API running on a Azure Web app. I'm trying to send the Bearer token or some sort of representation of when user has successfullly signed in, and hte Bot Framework will store the token and periodically check that token hasn't expired...

Answer (score 3):

The correct place to plug-in yourself is the [Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet/blob/complete/WebApp-B2C-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) file. And register yourself for one of the `OpenIdConnectNotifications`. The notification you need is `SecurityTokenValidated`. And you will need to add it similarly to the other two notifications which are already in the sample. Or just add the following line within the the `OpenIdConnectnotifications` initializer:

```
                SecurityTokenValidated = (notification) => {
                    return Task.Delay(0); 
                }
```

The `notification` parameter you get contains everything you need to know about the end user and his/her successfull authentication.